# Settings on php.ini ignored

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini

I can't get my server to obey the settings from `php.ini` (I'm trying to change `memory_limit` and  `upload_max_filesize`). As far as I can tell, I'm editing the correct file. `phpinfo()` gives:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
```

The file permission is `644`. There are also some extra `.ini` files on `/etc/php.d`, but none include any of the keys I'm trying to change. No matter what I do, `phpinfo` reports the default values on both "Local" and "Master" columns.

I also scanned my Apache config files, but found nothing related to PHP (besides loading the PHP module). The only way I was able to change those settings was by adding some `php_value` lines to my `.htaccess`.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

This is a virtual server, and I can perform root commands with `sudo`. I'm running Apache 2.1.3 and PHP 5.3.3. System info (from `uname -a`) is:

```
 Linux sesctbapp01 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 04:16:51 EST 2012 x86_64
```

Comment: Did you restart apache after you made the changes?

Comment: Yes, I tried both restarting and just "reloading".

Comment: Do the following and post back what it finds: find / -name php.ini

Comment: The output was just `/etc/php.ini`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you managed to get around it without using .htaccess files ?

Comment: @Euloiix no, I had to resort to .htaccess. But there must be a way!

Comment: @bfavaretto: Thank you for your answer. 
So I am trying to use a `.htaccess` file with the following content: 
`php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200`
but it does not resolve my 3Mo file upload issue. My .htaccess is at `/var/www/html` and my website entry point is at `/var/www/html/mywebsite`. apache is the file owner, and permissions are 775. 
Any idea of what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: @Euloiix Sorry, I have no idea! It worked for me...

Comment: @bfavaretto: No worries, I finally found it out. I had to modify the `AllowOverride` of my `httpd.conf` file to allow the use of .htaccess.

Comment: It can either be that those values are overwritten by the starter script (if using php-fpm) using the -d option or that the PHP script is setting it's own limit within the PHP files.

Beside that, no idea. One thing to keep in mind is that not all PHP modes support setting values via 
htqccess - just to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

write a file in your webserver called test.php:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then open it in your browser

there is a section

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
```

where you see the values, of all variables and where they are set:
Local Value means, set in .htaccess or inside the php-script with ini_set()

also try http://php.net/manual/de/function.ini-get-all.php to find out the source of the content of your variables.

i once had a stupid error, where i tried to set upload_max_filesize to 200M: i wrote "200MB" in php.ini, but it must be just "200M"
php interprets the incorrect value "200MB" as 0. Maybe some of this helps

Comment: Thanks, but this problem is still a mystery to me. It like if some other ini file is overriding mine, but I can't find any. Also, although `phpinfo()` reports my ini file as "Loaded Configuration File", the values under "Master" are always the defaults. The only way I can override them is from `.htaccess`, while I really wanted to define all my settings from `php.ini`...

Comment: maybe there is a bad typo in the php.ini so it is ignored completely and all default php values are used instead. can you post your `php.ini` somewhere?

Comment: Hm, I haven't thought of that! Here is my php.ini: http://pastebin.com/KxwjA3K1

Comment: can i see the output of your phpinfo() somewhere?

Comment: and try moving the `php.ini` file somewhere else and restart apache. if you see an error, you will know, that apache tries to use that file, if there is no error, you should look somewhere else. normally php.ini is at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

If using php-fpm (don´t know if thats your case tough) it is not enough to restart apache, you have to restart php-fpm.

For example, on an Ubuntu 20.04 server and php 7.4 fpm, i had to

```
/etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm restart
```

in order for my php.ini to get obeyed.

Answer (score 1):

Run `php -i` in the terminal and it will flag if you have any syntax errors in your php.ini. Such errors make Apache to not parse (ignore) directives quietly.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem yesterday. I established there was only one php.ini on the system, phpinfo() reported that indeed the correct php.ini was being used  for configuration, I stopped httpd checked that all instances had been killed then restarted it, but php was still using the same values. This had to mean that another process was reading and storing the original values in php.ini. Search for php in the process listing revealed multiple instances of php-fpm. Tried killing it and then
restarting apache. That solved the problem. Tried more more changes in php.ini and tried
using systemctl  reload php-fpm and yes of course it worked. I don't know when the switch away from mod_php was made, apparently years ago but somehow I've missed it and over 90% of the servers I manage still use mod_php. None of the guides I've read for applications like Moodle mention ifpm. All say make the change and restart apache none of them mention restarting fpm, but there you go. I'm guessing many of the queries raised on sites like serverfault are down this issue. systemctl start httpd starts the fpm daemon in additon to httpd but systemctl stop httpd does not stop php-fpm nor does sytemctl restart httpd restart it and a new systemctl start httpd will unsurprisingly just leave the old version running.

So the quick way to make changes is to modify php.ini and and then run
systemctl reload php-fpm
no need to touch the httpd daemon.